# Unable to Connect L2TP IPSec VPN on Mac OSX

Tags: vpn, mac-osx, ipsec, l2tp

I'm struggling to debug an issue connecting a Mac to a L2TP IPsec VPN.

Macbook Pro running Mojave 10.14.6, following instructions here https://forum.peplink.com/t/setting-up-l2tp-with-ipsec/8046

I turned on verbose logging and this is what I'm seeing in `/var/log/ppp.log` (VPN server address redacted)

It seems to get to the phase 1 negotiation, succeeds, and then just hangs and fails.  I'm surprised it never gets to the phase 2 negotiation.

```
Fri Mar  6 09:53:04 2020 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!
Fri Mar  6 09:53:04 2020 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!
Fri Mar  6 09:53:04 2020 : l2tp_get_router_address
Fri Mar  6 09:53:04 2020 : l2tp_get_router_address 192.168.1.1 from dict 1
Fri Mar  6 09:53:04 2020 : L2TP connecting to server 'X.X.X.X' (X.X.X.X)...
Fri Mar  6 09:53:04 2020 : IPSec connection started
Fri Mar  6 09:53:04 2020 : IPSec phase 1 client started
Fri Mar  6 09:53:04 2020 : IPSec phase 1 server replied
Fri Mar  6 09:53:34 2020 : IPSec connection failed
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with one of the laptop.
I saw in the Console output (which collect all logs and messages) that after Phase 2 started the racoon daemon tries to get the IKE Handler which does not exist anymore.
In the startup description it was mentioned something like `IKE lifetime: seconds`.

When I added:
`ikelifetime=1h`
in the ipsec.conf everything started successfully.

Have a try, it solved in my case)